# Is there a way to carry dim light/darkness around with me permanently?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, vision-and-light

In Pathfinder 1e, there were options (e.g. [Palelight Torch](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Palelight%20Torch)) to provide a long-term/permanent reduction of light in your vicinity.

My 2nd edition [Shadowdancer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=77) would love some portable darkness that is action efficient; always on (at least for an adventuring day) would be best, but fewer actions (Reaction > 1 Action > 2 Actions > 3 Actions), including retrieval is preferred if there is no permanent option. If there are hands-free options, those are preferred but not necessary.

This is for a current character, so details:

- Half-Orc Human Rogue 15
- Currently has a fair amount of liquid money and the ability to shop

  - Current settlement has 15th level items, but I can save up if there is something coming up
- Limited flexibility remaining with Feats; further Dedications are infeasible

I'd be interested to hear if there was an option for *other* characters to accomplish this as well, but that would essentially be above and beyond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Deepdread Claw, Darkness for 2 actions

Best I could find is the [Deepdread Claw](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=768), which allows you to cast [Darkness at 4th level](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=59) for only two actions for seemingly as many times as you want. It's certainly not ideal, as it takes a hand to hold, and is a Rare 14th level item, but it might be something you could grab, and even then this seems to be the only way to access some sort of darkness or dim light on command. It's 4000gp if you can find it.